# Inserting large amounts of data using SqlBulkCopy and DbGeography data types

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using an SqlBulkCopy to insery 10 000+ records into my DB but it won't work because of the DbGeography point.

I keep getting an exception message that gets thrown:

> "Specified type is not registered on the target server.System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography".

This is my code.

```
public void AddBulkRange(string tableName, List<TEntity> entities)
    {
        using (var context = new TContext())
        {
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

            string conectionString = context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

                using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction))
                {
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 2000;
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo." + tableName;
                    try
                    {
                        DataTable data = DataReaderConverterHelper.ToDataTable(entities);

                        //This just explicitly maps the columns in sqlBulkCopy to the table columns
                        foreach (DataColumn column in data.Columns)
                        {
                            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName));
                        }

                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(data);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the ToDataTable Method.

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<TEntity>(this IList<TEntity> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(TEntity));
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor property = properties[i];

            dt.Columns.Add(property.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(
        property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType);
        }
        object[] values = new object[properties.Count];
        foreach (TEntity item in data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                    values[i] = properties[i].GetValue(item);
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

The problem is the DbGeography point is throwing the exception.

The field type in my model.

```
public System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography geography_point { get; set; }
```

In the DB the field type is Geography.

I can insert if I use the method below but the problem is I get a timeout error that's why I want to use the SqlBulkCopy but as I said above it doesn't work because of that one data type.

```
public List<TEntity> AddRange(List<TEntity> entities)
    {
        int takeCount = 100;

        int counter = (entities.Count % takeCount) == 0
            ? (entities.Count / takeCount)
            : (entities.Count / takeCount) + 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            using (var context = new TContext())
            {
                List<TEntity> subList = entities.Skip(i * takeCount).Take(takeCount).ToList();

                context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

                context.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(subList);
                context.SaveChanges();
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }

        return entities;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography)?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - I'm not sure how to use this if I'm honest. Will it allow me to add my geography point to the DataTable and then save to the DB?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Thanks for that man, I wasn't sure how to use it but I found some stuff for it. It seems to be working perfectly with saving the points to the data after being converted. I'll post the final code below for others to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some input from @AlwaysLearning I made some changes and got the DbGeography working with the Data Table.

```
 public static DataTable ToDataTable<TEntity>(this IList<TEntity> data)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(TEntity));
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++)
        {
            PropertyDescriptor property = properties[i];

            if (property.PropertyType.Name == "DbGeography")
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(property.Name, typeof(SqlGeography));
                continue;
            }

            dt.Columns.Add(property.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(
        property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType);
        }
        object[] values = new object[properties.Count];
        foreach (TEntity item in data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                if (properties[i].PropertyType.Name == "DbGeography")
                {
                    DbGeography Point = (DbGeography)properties[i].GetValue(item);
                    SqlGeography newGeography = SqlGeography.Parse(Point.AsText()).MakeValid();
                    values[i] = newGeography;
                    continue;
                }
                values[i] = properties[i].GetValue(item);
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

All I did was convert the DbGeography data type to the SqlGeography type and it worked perfectly.